# Does usage of advanced language features decrease maintainability?

Tags: language-agnostic, maintainability, coding-style

On a code review, I've stumbled on an interesting idea, which I can't properly judge alone.

Is it OK to improve readability of code by means of not widely known language syntax? When the original writer didn't use a special syntax designated for solving a specific coding problem, and solved it by simulating with workarounds — is it worth to refactor it for clarity and conciseness? What if even the code reviewer didn't know about the language feature?

To be specific, I'll bring the exact issue I've met on the code review — but keep in mind that this is just an example.

So the original code was a little web service in Python. At some point, there arised a requirement for several request handlers to be protected with an authentication mechanism. Somebody solved it with inheritance:

```py
class AuthOnlyAccess:
    def GET(self, *args):
        if not hasattr(self, 'PROTECTED_GET'):
            raise web.Nomethod()

        if check_auth():
            return self.PROTECTED_GET(*args)
        else:
            raise web.Unauthorised()

    def POST(self, *args):
        if not hasattr(self, 'PROTECTED_POST'):
            raise web.Nomethod()

        if check_auth():
            return self.PROTECTED_POST(*args)
        else:
            raise web.Unauthorised()

...

class FooHandler(AuthOnlyAccess):
    def PROTECTED_GET(self, a, b, c):
        handle_foo_get(a, b, c)

    def PROTECTED_POST(self, x, y, z):
        handle_spam_eggs()

...
<more handlers deriving AuthOnlyAccess>
```

The refactorer found this code ugly and introduced a decorator:

```py
from functools import wraps
...

def requires_auth(wrapped_func):
    """ (a little doc telling that this is a decorator and how to use it) """
    @wraps(wrapped_func)
    def decorator(*args):
        if check_auth():
            return wrapped_func(*args)
        else 
            raise web.Unauthorized()

    return decorator

...

class FooHandler:
    @requires_auth
    def GET(self, a, b, c):
        handle_foo_get(a, b, c)

    @requires_auth
    def POST(self, x, y, z):
        handle_spam_eggs()

...
<more refactored handlers>
```

The reviewer argues that this change actually **decreases** maintainability, because most of the team doesn't know decorator syntax. So the next person visiting the refactored code could be puzzled by the construct — but not with the previous version.

There's also a convincing argument that **most of the codebase isn't in Python**, (the language is there only for that little web service), and hence team members aren't required to have even shallow knowledge of Python. However, to work with code, one's going to need to know its language, right?

And if you have the temptation to say that python decorators aren't *that* advanced syntax — please remember that this is only an example. Every language has its dark corners. (But to learn those corners means to become better.)

So the question is... Can you read unknown syntax? Is the elegance worth the surprise? At least, what are the tradeoffs and/or guidelines you can name? I do really need some opinions from the community of programming professionals.

Comment: How can this question be answered except with "it depends?"

Comment: @JasonTrue "it depends on: 1) ... 2) ... 3) ...".

Comment: If my team has low skill, should I lower the skill of my code?  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/203469/if-my-team-has-low-skill-should-i-lower-the-skill-of-my-code talks about closely related issues.

Comment: "So the question is... Can you read unknown syntax"? Of course. I'd learned it as needed. Especially for things as standard and well-established as Python decorators. To hear that there are professional programmers who would do otherwise is horrifying in the extreme.

Comment: I know what Python decorators are, and I don't even know Python. I find it very strange that a team of Python programmers doesn't. Honestly, if that is *really* the case then the solution is not to write dumber code but rather to get smarter colleagues.

Comment: @JörgWMittag the team is *not* a team of Python programmers. The main language is different. (I mentioned this specifically in the question.)

Comment: "If you think education is expensive, you should try ignorance."  - Derek Bok

Comment: If they are not .py proficient, then the original seems fine to me. The goal is to make money presumably, not write poetic code.

Comment: If the team is not proficient in python, and most of the product is not in python, then why are you using python at all? Doing so means you now have stuff that no one on the team is proficient at, and you have yet another dependency. Unless the plan is to move to python in the future, why fool with it at all?

Comment: @MichaelKohne because a webservice in Python is much simpler and reliable than webservice in C++.

Comment: I actually find both versions ugly, but oh well. IMO, the most important code characteristic after "code that works good enough" is "Is the code maintainable?". Choose what is easiest to understand and modify without side-effects BY PEOPLE WHO HAVE NEVER SEEN THE CODE BEFORE. I personally don't want to be stuck on the same project forever, so I try to write code that I can pass off to others so I can go onto new things. Whether your example makes things easier or harder is a matter of opinion. What do others in the group think? If a number of them think it is harder then it probably is.

Comment: @ulidtko - unless you don't have any python programmers. Then it's worse because you can't maintain it. Unless the plan is to go to python for more and more of the system, adding another language & dependency is bad for the project.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The refactored example is *objectively superior* because it has less repeated code. Therefore, that implementation is actually *simpler*, and probably shorter. There is also the argument that the original code in your example is an ad-hoc implementation of [traits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_%28computer_programming%29) (or an awkward expression of the strategy pattern), the result being unnecessarily complex code.

In this case, you should be using decorators, even when most of your devs don't know them. This adds only a *single extra concept* to that piece of code, which is very cheap considering that programming is generally rich in fancy new concepts. The necessary information can and should be added in a terse comment explaining this feature, which should also contain a link to the relevant docs.

For other language features, the same considerations should be made:

- Which version is simpler and expresses a solution closer to the language of the problem domain?
- What is the cost of educating future maintainers? Can everything be explained in a short comment, or would you have to hold a lecture on category theory?
- What is the cost of *not* educating future maintainers? Just two extra lines here, or having to write baby code to the end of your life?

  > <del>Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day.</del>
  >   <del>Teach a man to fish and feed him for his life.</del>
  >   Dumb down your code for a programmer and he can understand it at once.
  >   Teach a programmer advanced techniques, and he'll understand all your future code on his own.

Comment: *objectively superior* if shorter code is the only metric.. don't forget about stack depth, etc.

Comment: @DavidCowden *objectively superior* under maintainability and correctness metrics like DRY, separation of concerns, etc. which trumps small inefficiencies like an single extra stack frame.

Comment: @delnan that's a rather subjective response, sir. http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy

Comment: @DavidCowden Which part is subjective, that DRY/separation of concerns is more important than stack depth? Because I don't see how adherence DRY and separation and concern can be subjective.

Comment: @delnan the general notion that abstraction always trumps efficiency.  Although we are on *programmers* so maybe people operate under that assumption by default.

Comment: @amon There's another saying to go along with the "Teach a man a fish".  `Build a man a fire, he's warm for the night.  Set a man on fire, he's warm for the rest of life.`

Answer (score 8):

This is something that you need to take on a case by case basis. I would argue that you should use unfamiliar features of a language if it would improve clarity and make future maintenance easier (both of which your example accomplishes in my opinion).

You should *never* use features just because you want to be clever or because you want to use the feature for the sake of it. On the other hand, I don't think you should ever avoid using a feature that would improve the code simply because the other developers on your team don't know how to use it yet. If they are worth their salt they will soon learn and use it themselves if the idea has merit. Developers that refuse to adopt possibly superior techniques just because they've never seen or used them before should raise big red flags.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would say that coding conventions are a place where restrictions on language usage are stored. Otherwise every time people will have different idea about what is familiar for a team and what isn't.

When choosing a subset you create a new language. It certainly shares many things with "host" language, but is different. Some things may become simpler, some - harder.

Why define subset:

1. Host language has features considered dangerous (e.g. limiting preprocessor in C++)
2. Your needs are much smaller than language abilities (e.g. JSON as a subset of JavaScript)
3. You have specific needs (e.g. supporting old versions of a compiler without support for the newest language features)

Why stick to the whole language:

1. The new features are there for a reason (e.g. your case)
2. Better support ("how to solve it in LISP?" will be answered faster than "how to solve this in LISP without lambda functions")
3. Hiring new developers simpler (for subset the candidates should be able *and* comfortable to work under restrictions you have)
4. You trust that the whole language was designed by better language designer(s) than you :)